# Wso2is: How to setup different certificates for SSL and SAML assertion signing

Tags: ssl, wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I'm implementing a SAML2 based IdP proxy to authenticate users coming from a large federation to use my own services. How to setup different certificates, one for the SAML signing and another trusted for the HTTPS ssl ?
Thanks
Regards
francesco

Answer (score 0):

In WSO2 IS implementation we used two keystore. Keystores are located in

> [wso2is]/repository/resources/security

1. wso2carbon.jks - this keystore contains a public and private  key pair. It is used by default in your carbon server
2. client-truststore.jks - this is default trust store.This keystore used for SSL communication.

You can found more details here[1]. Here you can found how to add ca cert to wso2 truststore[2]. If you need to create new keystore here the details[3].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Setting+up+Keystores
[2] https://udaraliyanage.wordpress.com/2014/06/16/add-a-ca-certificate-to-wso2-truststore/
[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Creating+New+Keystores

Comment: Thanks Pradeepa. As by documentation however I understand that client-truststore.jks is the keystore where to place the certificates for the third parties that wso2 needs to trust. In my case I need to setup a trusted certificate for the "https://idp.cloud.tisparkle.com:9443/samlsso?spEntityID=xxxxxxx" endpoint that should be different for the main one that is used for saml signing. Does the client-truststore.jks help me for this also ?...thanks and best regards....francesco

Comment: Hi. I found a method to satisfy my requirement. I changed the keystore pointed from conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml to one that contain my SSL certificate and it seems to work. Please can you confirm me that this is the right solution ?